# 2D array as a string. Initialising

Tags: java

I've got this question from a past paper and I'm unsure if I'm right.

> "Write down the Java code to declare and initialise a two-dimensional array with the days
>   of the week and their three letter abbreviations."

So what I can derive from this is it needs to be a 2d array as a string as we're storing the days of the week and the abbreviations.

Would this implementation be suitable answer for the question?

```
string[][] g;
g = new string[7][1];
g[0][0] = "Monday"
g[0][1] = "Mon"
g[1][0] = "Tuesday"
g[1][1] = "Tue"
```

Comment: Correct apart from a few things. `String` needs to be capitalised in both cases. Your array should be 7x2 - 7 days, 2 strings per day. Easy mistake to make because when arrays are indexed, the max index would be 1, but the size is 2.

Comment: Nop, for the sake of the data description you could use only one array too... you are just missing the three letters abbreviations part...

Comment: Indexes in array are zero-based. `new Type[size]` creates array for `size` elements, but indexes of these elements would be `0` till `size-1`.

Comment: So just to clarify, with the amendment of the length and the correct casing for the string would it be the correct answer for the question from the past paper. cheers

Comment: @Jeremy Yep. Obviously you would need to go up to Sunday which would be `g[6][0]`  and `g[6][1]`. I doubt whether they would subtract marks for the `String` because the question isn't trying to test that knowledge. Still, it's a good thing to remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost.

The dimensions of the array of arrays you want is `[7][2]` -- it's no different from 1D arrays. `int[] x = new int[2]` has two entries, `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

`String` is a class, and classes begin with a capital letter.

You've forgotten the semicolon on most of your assignments.

So:

```
String[][] g;
g = new String[7][2];
g[0][0] = "Monday";
g[0][1] = "Mon";
g[1][0] = "Tuesday";
g[1][1] = "Tue";
```

... and so on.

Done like this, it's a correct answer to the question you've been given, but it's not how a seasoned Java developer would write it. Many would make declaration and creation one step:

```
String[][] g = new String[7][2];
g[0][0] = "Monday"; // etc
```

Many would populate it using an *array literal*:

```
String[][] g = new String[][] {
       { "Monday", "Mon" },
       { "Tuesday", "Tue" },
       // etc.
};
```

Note that when you do it this way, you don't need to specify the size, because it will be as big as the number of entries in the literal.

Comment: FWIW I think it's ridiculous the focus beginners' Java courses seem to have on arrays. Yes, you should learn about them, but it should come later.

Comment: new string[7][2]; = new String[7][2]; Edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You can declare an array in this way for it to be more readable:

```
String daysOfWeek[][] = {
    { "Monday", "Mon" },
    { "Tuesday", "Tue" },
    // <...>
};
```

Comment: His question was "Would this implementation... be suitable...?" He did not ask for you to do it a different way.

Comment: Also you don't need the `new String[][]`.